# split data frame and create stacked percent barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame looks like this:

```
plant  distance
one      1
one      3
one      2
one      3
one      7
one      4
one      6
one      8
one      9
two      1
two      6
two      4
two      8
two      5
two      3
three ……
```

I want to split `distance` of each level into groups by interval(for instance,interval=3).

```
plant  distance group
  one      1    1
  one      3    1
  one      2    1
  one      3    1
  one      7    3
  one      4    2
  one      6    2
  one      8    3
  one      9    3
  two      1    1
  two      6    2
  two      4    2
  two      8    3
  two      5    2
  two      3    1
  three ……
```

And compute percentage of each group

```
plant group percentage
one     1     0.44
one     2     0.22
one     3     0.33
two     1     0.33
two     2     0.50
two     3     0.17
three ……
```

Finally, plot the percentages of each level of each group similar like this:
[image]

and I do not know how to split each level by interval. Sorry for my English! Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you want? What have you tried? For example, you could split your data frame by using `split(my_data$distance, my_data$plant)`, you could group it by `cut(my_data$distance, breaks = seq(min(my_data$distance), max(my_data$distance), 3))` etc.

Comment: @lukeA Thank you for your reply, I have tried many times and I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
my_data %>%
  mutate(group = factor(cut(distance, seq(0, max(distance), 3), F))) %>%
  group_by(plant, group) %>%
  summarise(percentage = n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage = percentage / sum(percentage)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = plant, y = percentage, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, and it is efficient. I got an error: `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`. Could you talk a bit more about the '%>%', 'group_by', and 'mutate'?

Comment: `mutate` is `my_data$group <- factor(cut(my_date$distance, seq(0, max(my_data$distance), 3), F)))`. `group_by` groups the data set for `summarise`. `%>%` passes my_data from operation to operation, if you want to put it like that. You'll find plenty of info by google'ing. I'm using dplyr_0.4.0 and  ggplot2_1.0.0 - the code works here with your example data.

Comment: We have used the symbol `%>%` to chain operations,  and how to break the chain and save the plot?

Comment: If you want to save the resulting data frame and the plot separately: `dat <- my_data %>%   mutate(group = factor(cut(distance, seq(0, max(distance), 3), F))) %>%   group_by(plant, group) %>%   summarise(percentage = n()) %>%   mutate(percentage = percentage / sum(percentage)); p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = plant, y = percentage, fill = group)) +    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack"); p`

Comment: I found a small problem that when I used  your solution to group the data, the last group was `NA`. For instance, we divide the array of 1 to 10 by `interval=3` into four groups, i.e.  `group 1(1 2 3)`, `group 2(4 5 6)`, `group 3(7 8 9)` and `group 4(10)`, but `group 4` was `NA`, because the length of `group 4` was less than the `interval=3`, so my question is how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post a new question using a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have post a new question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368010/split-data-and-create-stacked-percent-barplot-in-r-post2) .