# split data into groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

My data frame looks like this:

```
plant   distance
one 0
one 1
one 2
one 3
one 4
one 5
one 6
one 7
one 8
one 9
one 9.9
two 0
two 1
two 2
two 3
two 4
two 5
two 6
two 7
two 8
two 9
two 9.5
```

I want to split distance of each level into groups by interval(for instance,interval=3), and compute percentage of each group. Finally, plot the percentages of each level of each group similar like this:

[image]

my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(cut(distance, seq(0, max(distance), 3), F))) %>% 
  group_by(plant, group) %>% 
  summarise(percentage = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = percentage / sum(percentage))
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = plant, y = percentage, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
p
```

But my plot is shown below: the `group 4` was missing.
[image]

And I found that the `dat` was wrong, the `group 4` was `NA`.

[image]

The likely reason is that the length of `group 4` was less than the `interval=3`, so my question is how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.The reason is that the `cut(distance, seq(0, max(distance), 3), F)` did not include the maximum and minimum values.

Here is my solution:

```
dat <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(cut(distance, seq(from = min(distance), by = 3,   length.out = n()/ 3 + 1),  include.lowest = TRUE)))  %>% 
  count(plant, group) %>%
  group_by(plant) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))
```